# Why is everything shifted to the right in my conversion from idx file format to pixel matrix?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, neural-network, mnist

In my journey to explore neural networks and machine learning, I stumbled upon MNIST hand written digits dataset. When trying to convert from the provided file format (idx) to a useful pixel matrix that i can input into my neural network, every value was shifted to the right, for no reason:

[image: As you can see]

Here is the conversion process, along with some functions that were involved:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { hex_to_decimal } = require("../utils/hex_to_decimal");
/**
 *
 * @param {fs.PathOrFileDescriptor} path
 * @returns Promise<Buffer>
 */
function read_idx_file(path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        reject(err.message);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

/**
 *
 * @param {string | NodeJS.ArrayBufferView} data
 * @param {fs.PathOrFileDescriptor} path
 * @returns Promise<void>
 */
function input_into_json(data, path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.writeFile(path, data, {}, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err.message);
      else resolve();
    });
  });
}

// inputting training-images into json file
read_idx_file("../samples/unzipped/train-images.idx3-ubyte")
  .then((data) => {
    const output = [];
    let temp_row_arr = [];
    let temp_col_arr = [];
    let temp_index = 8;
    while (data[temp_index] !== undefined) {
      for (let i = temp_index; i - temp_index < 28; i++) {
        temp_row_arr.push(hex_to_decimal(data[i]));
      }
      temp_index += 28;
      temp_col_arr.push(temp_row_arr);
      temp_row_arr = [];
      if (temp_col_arr.length === 28) {
        output.push(temp_col_arr);
        temp_col_arr = [];
      }
    }
    input_into_json(
      JSON.stringify(output),
      "../samples/json/training-images.json"
    );
  })
  .then(() => console.log("done"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The raw output (so the problem for sure isn't with my formatter)

[image: here]

Any help explaining this would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

[IDX format explanation](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/IDX_file_format.html)

Comment: You’re not reading the file header.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is that necessary? I already know what information the header contains so I am directly jumping to the data to process it

Comment: I hadn't noticed you skipped the header, I was assuming data is shifted because the header is still in there. Is that 8 bytes you skip? The header is 4 bytes for the magic number + 3 x 4 bytes for the array sizes (it's a 3D array I presume), so you need to skip 16 bytes, not 8.

Comment: @CrisLuengo omg thank you so much. I have kept the same settings from when I was getting the labels. This was it